# Getting Auto Layout to Work from Maximum Value to Zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, visual-format-language

I am using the following Visual Format Language (VFL) to set the maximum height of the UIView.

```
// this is here to stop the auto layout from reporting that the guides has
// ambiguous layout
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[topGuide]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottomGuide]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


// center the stop view in the super view, both lines below are needed
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(>=12)-[stopView(<=400)]-(>=12)-|"
                                                                  options: 0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
// set the height to a ratio of the width
NSLayoutConstraint *con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:stopView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        relatedBy:0 toItem:stopView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                       multiplier:0.66667f constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:con2];
```

But VFL starts the height from ZERO. Once the constraint is met, it stops and produce the following image:

[image: Height Starts From Zero].

When I change the Visual Format String to `@"|-(>=12)-[stopView(<=400,>=100)]-(>=12)-|"` the height starts from 100 and produce the following:

[image: Height starts from 100]

What VFL can I add to have the height starts from 400 and go down until it meets the constraint?

Comment: You don't have any constraints for the vertical size (height).

Comment: Later in the code I have another constraint that sets the height to a ratio of the width.